# What is this called in Android?

Tags: android

[image]

It comes once in an application during the start to show screenshots of what app can do and/or how.

Comment: It's called an ad. You have installed some nasty adware, probably

Comment: Dotted Viewpager .

Comment: it's call view pager check this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/

Comment: you mean [app intro](https://github.com/apl-devs/AppIntro)?

Comment: This is called Intro slider

Comment: Dont downvote if you dont want to reply or you dont know

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with programming, so I'm voting to close this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That screens calls intro screens.
that using [viewpager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

if you want to first time when application is installed.
The you have manage boolean flag when application is installed using [sharedpreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html).
check at the splash screen every time.